# Warning: There is no class model available for code generation in Visual Paradigm

Tags: java, code-generation, visual-paradigm

I'm dealing with a problem in my `Visual Paradigm project`. I created some `Java sources` and I did instant `Reverse` with them. Then I dragged the model elements of the classes to the Class diagram. I modified the class diagram adding some operations to these classes and I tried to update the code.

But I got the warning

```
"There is no class model available for code generation"
```

and the `Java sources` have not been updated with the new operations.

Could someone help me with this error?

Comment: it's been some years I don't use Visual Paradigm, but as far as i remember in order to keep your code and your UML diagrams synchronized is better to use the Round Trip functionality. This is a [link](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/276/381/7486_generateorup.html) from Visual Paradigm web site

Comment: What is the VP version ?

Comment: Have you tried eclipse - visual paradigm plugin ?

Answer (score 1):

Check the version of your SDE. Versions lower than 4.2 are not well maintained. Moreover the integration capabilities have been merged with Visual Paradigm-UML now. Its Latest Version is 14.0 right now.